# Is there a way to make a request server-side on a client-side rendered PWA?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, mqtt

I'm building a small PWA so I can control a few smarthome devices through MQTT. It's written in React and hosted by an Nginx webserver. Currently, on load of the application, it uses `MQTT.js` to make a connection to the MQTT server over `wss` on port `8883`. But this feels wrong-- my phone shouldn't be connecting to the MQTT server directly, the requests should be getting made from the Nginx container to the MQTT container, not my phone. While I'm sure this is possible I'm not sure how to even start setting this up. What is needed/what should I be searching for?

Comment: Why shouldn't the phone be connecting to the broker? There is no reason why NGINX couldn't act as a proxy for the broker if you want to pin it all to a single port, but other than that there isn't a clear question here.

Comment: @hardillb A couple reasons. First of all, if I want to be able to use this app from the open web, I would have to open up the MQTT port on my router as well as HTTPS, and opening unnecessary ports is something I'd rather avoid. Also, establishing the connection on app open takes extra time that going through the Nginx container would avoid because the connection would persist.

Comment: No need to open a second port, NGINX will happily proxy for the broker for MQTT over WebSockets connection all on the same port. And latency will be MUCH better using MQTT and retained messages to get current device states than having to poll with HTTP.